# Send Image with Ajax to database (php) without reloading

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, bootstrap-modal

I create a bootstrap modal popup form to add picture in gallery page, I developed the php & ajax code because i want without page reloading here :-

the problem is when I want to send image to database I show this error

`Notice: Undefined index: photo in ....`

I can't send image.

**this's my ajax code**

```js
$(function() {
  //twitter bootstrap script
  $("button#submit").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
   url: "image.php",
   data: $('form.contact').serialize(),
   success: function(msg){
    $("#thanks").html(msg)
          $("#myModal").modal('hide');
         },
  error: function(){
   alert("failure");
   }
  });
 });
});
```

**And this's Image.php file**

```html
include 'db.php';

if(isset($_POST['titre'])){
 $titre = strip_tags($_POST['titre']);

 $image_name = $_FILES['photo']['name'];
 $image_tmp = $_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'];
 $image_size = $_FILES['photo']['size'];
 $image_ext = pathinfo($image_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
 $image_path = '../images/'.$image_name;
 $image_db_path = 'images/'.$image_name;

  if($image_size < 1000000000){
    if($image_ext == 'jpg' || $image_ext == 'png' || $image_ext = 'gif'){
 if(move_uploaded_file($image_tmp,$image_path)){
 $ins_sql = "INSERT INTO media (Images_md, Id_Pro, Value, Title) VALUES ('$image_db_path', '0', 'galerie', '$titre')";
  if(mysqli_query($conn,$ins_sql)){
   echo '<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable">
<button aria-hidden="true" data-dismiss="alert" class="close" type="button"> × </button>
Success! Well done its submitted. </div>';
   }else {
    echo '
<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable">
<button aria-hidden="true" data-dismiss="alert" class="close" type="button"> × </button>
Error ! Change few things. </div>';
     }
    }else {
    echo '
<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable">
<button aria-hidden="true" data-dismiss="alert" class="close" type="button"> × </button>
Sorry, Image hos not been uploaded. </div>
    ';
    }
   }
   else {
    echo '
<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable">
<button aria-hidden="true" data-dismiss="alert" class="close" type="button"> × </button>
Please Add a jpg OR png OR gif Image. </div>
    ';
   }
    }else {
    echo '
<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable">
<button aria-hidden="true" data-dismiss="alert" class="close" type="button"> × </button>
Image File Size is much bigger then Expect. </div>
    ';
   }
}
```

**and this's myModal code :**

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
<h4 class="modal-title">Ajouter Photo</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
<form class="contact">
<div class="form-group">
<label  class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="inputEmail3">Titre</label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
<input type="text" name="titre" class="form-control" placeholder="Titre"/>
</div>
</div>
<br><br>
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-sm-2 control-label"      for="inputEmail3">Photo</label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
<input type="file" name="photo" class="form-control" />
</div>
</div>
</form>
</div><br><br>
<div class="modal-footer">
<button class="btn btn-success" name="submit" id="submit">submit</button>
<a href="#" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Can you help me to send image with ajax jQuery?

Comment: @Nytrix I think I need to add something to ajax code but I'm beginner in ajax language for that I make this post

Comment: @saad Now I see, you need to send the whole form. Look at the comment above me, that is how you need to solve this. Always research first, then make a post, as this is a duplicate.

Comment: @RajdeepPaul The problem is I'm beginner In Ajax Language I don't know what I need to add in my code, And the big problem I need to finish my project today because I need to give it tomorrow to my teacher :'(

Comment: @saad I've given an answer below. Hopefully this will solve your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make few changes in your AJAX script, such as:

- Set the following options, `processData: false` and `contentType: false` in your AJAX request.  From [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/),

  > **contentType** (default: `'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'`) 
  >   Type: `Boolean` or `String` 
  >   When sending data to the server, use this content type. Default is "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8", which is fine for most cases. If you explicitly pass in a content-type to `$.ajax()`, then it is always sent to the server (even if no data is sent). As of jQuery 1.6 you can pass `false` to tell jQuery to not set any content type header.

  and

  > **processData** (default: `true`) 
  >   Type: `Boolean` 
  >   By default, data passed in to the data option as an object (technically, anything other than a string) will be processed and transformed into a query string, fitting to the default **content-type "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"**. If you want to send a DOMDocument, or other non-processed data, set this option to `false`.
- And if you're uploading file through AJAX, use [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects) object. But keep in mind that old browsers don't support FormData object, FormData support starts from the following desktop browsers versions: IE 10+, Firefox 4.0+, Chrome 7+, Safari 5+, Opera 12+.

So change your jQuery script in the following way,

```
$(function(){
    //twitter bootstrap script
    $("button#submit").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "image.php",
            data: new FormData($('form')[0]),
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function(msg){
                $("#thanks").html(msg)
                $("#myModal").modal('hide');
            },
            error: function(){
                alert("failure");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanksssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss Yeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeep It's work

Comment: @saad You're very welcome! :-)